# Configs in fish

Tags: linux, shell, fish

I just started using `fish`.I have used `zsh` and `bash` before. Where do I place the configs in `fish`?

Sample of configs- https://bpaste.net/show/92f553c9aab8

I tried it in `~/config/fish/config.fish` but it gave me errors. Errors I got: https://bpaste.net/show/e136cc91f188

Replacing `&&` with `;` removes the errors. But does it do the same thing? If not how can I achieve the same as with `&&`.

**Error with equals:**

```
$ iitpi conda update --all
Unsupported use of '='. To run 'https_proxy=http://10.10.78.21:3128' with a modified environment, please use 'env http_proxy=http://10.10.78.21:3128 https_proxy=http://10.10.78.21:3128…'
in function “iitpi”
        called on standard input
        with parameter list “conda update --all”
```

Comment: Hmmm why the downvote? What's the obvious I am missing.

Comment: You're apparently missing the documentation: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html

Comment: @glennjackman please check the update.

Answer (score 1):

A few errors in there. fish has different syntax than zsh and bash

Not this:

```
alias ipy="(jupyter qtconsole &)"
```

in fish `(...)` is the command substitution syntax, like zsh/bash backticks or `$(...)`. Do this:

```
function ipy
    jupyter qtconsole &
end
```

because fish aliases are just syntactic sugar for functions

In bash, `(...)` runs the contents in a subshell. If you really want to do that in fish, you have to be explicit:

```
function ipy
    fish -c 'jupyter qtconsole' &
end
```

---

`&&` is bash; the `and` command is fish, so not this:

```
command1 && command2_if_cmd1_succeeds
```

but this

```
command1; and command2_if_cmd1_succeeds
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixes most of the stuff except the equals to sign problem. Please check the edit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Fish configs go to `~/.config/fish/` (note the dot). I'd avoid a single config.fish and instead use individual files for every application / subject in `conf.d/`, i.e. `~/.config.fish/conf.d/10-homebrew.fish`.